# Is it possible to make a gpu cluster (accessible via ssh) accessible like local gpus?

Tags: matlab, ssh, cuda, gpu, remote-access

I can access a gpu cluster via ssh. I want to run matlab code on it without installing matlab on the cluster. That's why I want to make the gpus accessible like local gpus.
e.g. matlab code

```
gpuDevice()
```

should not only show my local gpu, but also the remote ones. Is that possible? Do I have to configure that somehow in CUDA?

Comment: that would be a lot of latency ...

Comment: better to install matlab on the cluster and run computation there?

Comment: yep - also lowers bandwidth quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

[rcuda](http://www.rcuda.net) is what you are looking for. However, using a remote GPU has [severe performance](http://sc15.supercomputing.org/sites/all/themes/SC15images/tech_poster/poster_files/post202s2-file3.pdf) implications due to the high-latency, low-bandwidth nature of the link to the remote GPU. So running the entire code (matlab in your case) on the remote machine is the better choice where possible.

Answer (score -1):

May be using the docker swarm to make your cluster can answer your problem. Each user can be seperated and you can access each gpu card in your established container.

Comment: Can you pls add more details, links to relevant documentation, etc...?

Comment: How does using Docker make a remote GPU look like a local one?